# Why does SonarQube says “May expose internal representation by incorporating reference to mutable object” when using @SuperBuilder.?

Tags: spring-boot, sonarqube, lombok, spring-annotations

0

I do not understand why do I keep getting this SonarQube error message:

**Malicious code - May expose internal representation by incorporating reference to mutable object**

This code stores a reference to an externally mutable object into the internal representation of the object.  If instances are accessed by untrusted code, and unchecked changes to the mutable object would compromise security or other important properties, you will need to do something different. Storing a copy of the object is better approach in many situations.

Strange thing is it is showing the error message in one of the model but not on the other.

here is the picture of the one that is giving the error message:
[image]

And here is the picture of the one that is not showing any error message:
[image]

Could someone explain me why am i getting the sonar error for @SuperBuilder in one and not in other?